# webpack bundle js n("./debug/sass/list-item.scss")

Tags: webpack, bundle

[when I use webpack, I bundle my files ,which generate code like this.

I think 'n("./debug/sass/list-item.scss")' is not correct，how do I deal with it?
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czXdt.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czXdt.jpg)

Comment: Can you give us more informations? I have no idea what are you asking about actually?

Comment: @exoslav I'm sorry that my English is not good.

'$jn([6,7],{"./debug/app.c.js":function(e,t,n){"use strict";function o(e){...}'  is a
part of code which webpack bundled.why does it have ''./debug/app.c.js "(moudle.filename)? thanks

Comment: I know “./debug/app.c.js” is unique value for  module. C an webpack generate a easy and short name for moudle not like moudle.fliename